# Display cell in a TableViewController chronologically - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to display cell chronologically in a *TableViewController*. I use a Item.swift and a ItemStore.swift to save data but when I display with data in cell I have:
1(first item save)-
2(second item save)-
3(...)

But I want: 
3-
2-
1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just reverse your data array before reloading table data

```
yourTableViewDataArray.reverse() { $0.yourTableViewDataArray > $1.yourTableViewDataArray }
yourTableViewDataArray.reloadData();
```